# Ionic : navigating to a second page within a lazy module causes 'Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment' exception

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-router

I have an Ionic (5) application where I am using Angular routing.

I have a number of different pages that are in lazy loaded `feature` modules, and have all these routes added to the app.modules router, and all works fine.

I have just added a second page (eg a details page) into one of the existing `feature` modules. I did NOT add a new modules for it, I just made it part of the feature page's module.

In the module.ts of this feature module, I have added the new `details` page to `declarations`, and `entryComponents`, and I have added it to the routes...

```
    const routes: Routes = [
        {
            path: '', 
            component: MainFeaturePage, 
            canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard]
        },
        {
            path: 'details-page',
            component: DetailsPage
        }
    ];
```

and of course I have `RouterModule.forChild(routes),` in the `imports` section.

However, when I now try to navigate to this page, via another componnent within this lazy module, ie I call

```
this.navCtrl.navigateForward('details-page');
```

I get the exception `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment'`

If I get the code to break on the exception, I can see the module it is looking in is the root module, and not the module of the feature module...

[image]

Any idea what I am doing wrong here, and how I can make it see the route as declared in the feature module?

**[UPDATE1]**

I tried using the full path,

```
this.navCtrl.navigateForward('feature-page/details-page');
```

I no longer get the error, but it just seems to reload the main feature page

Comment: why aren't you using angular routing? https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/navigation. import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class LoginComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router){}

  navigate(){
    this.router.navigate(['/detail'])
  }
}

Comment: I am pretty sure that Ionics new `NavController` does use Angular routing underneath (adding their own animations on top), as explained [here](https://www.joshmorony.com/using-angular-routing-with-ionic-4/#:~:text=The%20NavController%20is%20included%20in,has%20retained%20the%20same%20name.) At any rate I did try `this.router.navigateByUrl` and have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention in your answer, you can give the full path.

```js
this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/feature-page/details-page');
```

Or you can specify that it is relative to the current route.

```js
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
...
public constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    ...
```

```js
this.navCtrl.navigateForward("details-page", {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});
```

Comment: The relative looks good, but I could not get to work. Perhaps because I pass some data to me main route. Eg I need to use /feature-page/aa/details-page where the aa is a placeholder for the data I otherwise pass

Comment: You might try `this.navCtrl.navigateForward("../aa/details-page", {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});`.

Comment: Strange for me the `../aa/details-page` still did not find the route. Ill have to investigate why not, perhaps something else is going on that is interfering.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was I needed the full path..

```
this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/feature-page/details-page');
```

Note the '/' in front of the `/feature-page`

This did work once I got rid of another error.